# java string escaping issue

Tags: java, string, escaping

I have the following code:

```
if (file.getParent().equals("Care Compass\\js")) {
    System.out.println(Files.getNameWithoutExtension("$$$"+entry.getName()));
}
```

The sysout for

```
file.getParent()
```

is the string:

```
Care Compass\js
```

But the above If condition won;t hold true. What am i missing here?

Thanks!

Posting some more code as per the comments:

```
try {
    ZipFile zipFileTemp = new ZipFile(zipFile);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> enumeration = zipFileTemp.entries();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
        ZipEntry entry = enumeration.nextElement();
        File file;
        if(Files.getFileExtension(entry.getName()).equals("js")){
            jsFileName = entry.getName();
            file = new File(entry.getName());
            System.out.println("****%"+file.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("****%%"+file.getName());

            System.out.println("****"+entry.getName());
            System.out.println(entry.getName());

            System.out.println("p="+file.getParent());

            if (file.getParent().toString().equals("Care Compass\\js")) {
                System.out.println(Files.getNameWithoutExtension("$$$"+entry.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is this:

```
****%C:\Workspaces\CCQueryHotkey\sqlfindertoolMultiThreaded\Care     
Compass\js\carecompass-ui-1.3.0.6.min.js
****%%carecompass-ui-1.3.0.6.min.js
****Care Compass/js/carecompass-ui-1.3.0.6.min.js
Care Compass/js/carecompass-ui-1.3.0.6.min.js
p=Care Compass\js
carecompass-ui-1.3.0.6.min
```

Comment: probably there is a whitespace around it... Use `file.getParent().trim().equals()` instead.

Comment: I would also use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()` in this situation...

Comment: What happens if you try: `file.getParent().equals("Care Compass"+File.separator+"js")`?

Comment: What is the type of `file`? What does `getParent()` return?

Comment: file.getParent() returns "Care Compass\js" in the console

Comment: posting the entire code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is... sorry .. `Files.getNameWithoutExtension("$$$"+entry.getName())` is stripping the `$$$` .. this was working, it is just that the string was being stripped out by `.getNameWithoutExtension()`

Comment: Thanks for cleaning the comment up, but instead of down-voting for casual comment, a valid question resolved by myself, a newbie like me can use some advice first. I am sure you will find many places in SO people comment casually. Anyways, thanks for your time. Not everyone is familiar with SO markdowns.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure file.getParent( ) returns string? sysout would print the toString( ) value, so use file.getParent().toString().equals in your if condition

Comment: yes file.getParent( ) returns string. I used your suggestion but the if condition is still false

Comment: In that case I suspect that the ' \' you see in the sysout is not really '\' but some other (probably unicode) character. Print the value of the character and try to find out what it is